# How to make javascript code work with button to reorder table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**This code below performs positioning of rows in the table.**

The code below in javascript works perfectly with the input type = "button"

```
<input type = "button" value = "move up" class = "move up" />
```

**How to make the javascript function below work with button below?**

```
<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-light" value = "move up">
   <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"> </ span>
</button>
```

**Javascript code I'm using right below**

```
$('#mytable input.move').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
        row.prev().before(row);
    else
        row.next().after(row);
});
```

**Code Html**

```
<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="move up" class="move up" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="move up">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="move down" class="move down" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="move down">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-down"></span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="move up" class="move up" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="move up">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="move down" class="move down" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="move down">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-down"></span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add an event listener??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the new markup using a `button` to do the same as the `input` does, change the script to this

```
$('#mytable button.move').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
        row.prev().before(row);
    else
        row.next().after(row);
});
```

and then add `move up` to the `button`s class

```
<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-light move up" value = "move up">
   <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"> </ span>
</ button>
```

---

If you can't add the classes to the `button`, use this script and evaluate the `button`'s *value* attribute instead, to find if to go "up" or "down".

```
$('#mytable button[value="move up"]').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($(this).val().contains('up'))
        row.prev().before(row);
    else
        row.next().after(row);
});
```

*Note, in the above i used the attribute selector `button[value="move up"]` to target the the `button`. One can of course use one of its existing classes as well.*

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `input.move` make the element to `button.move` since the elemet is a button not an `input`. Here is the updated JS.

```
$('#mytable button.move').click(function() { 
var row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
if ($(this).hasClass('up'))//update call here or add to html 
class row.prev().before(row); 
 else row.next().after(row); 
});
```

Observe the comment above update the class there are add up to the buttons class like this...

```
 <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-light up" value = "move up">    
    <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"> </ span> 
    </ button>
```